# Android:how to clear drawn path using eraser

Tags: android, paint, android-canvas

this is my code for erasing drawn path.

```
  mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

it erases the path along with background color. i want that it erase only path not along with background color.

to set background color m using the following code

```
  canvas.drawColor(coolor);
```

how to clear only path.can anyone help...